# CSS when dynamically creating a component

Tags: css, dynamiccomponent

I am dynamically creating the following checkbox component.  I want to have the checkbox line up next to or above the label.  I believe I need to use CSS to do this.  I don't know how to dynamically add CSS to this.

```
                $A.createComponent(

                "ui:inputCheckbox",
                { 
                    "value" : component.getReference("v.EventRSVP."+ fieldAPIName),
                    "aura:id": "checkbox",
                    "label": fieldLabel
                },
```

Comment: Have you tried passing a "class" attribute and then placing the class in your calling component's CSS?

Comment: I did try that.  It is acting as if the new component doesn't recognize the class in the calling component.

Comment: I just tested this on both a dynamically created custom component as well as a standard... and have the same issue -- it does not seem to recognize it. You may need to create a custom component that acts as a wrapper around the ui:inputCheckbox to provide the styling you desire... and then dynamically create that component rather than the ui:inputCheckbox directly.